# What does anchor error `2003` mean

Tags: anchor, anchor-test

What does the error for `A raw constraint was violated` mean?

```
    errorCode: { code: 'ConstraintRaw', number: 2003 },
    errorMessage: 'A raw constraint was violated',
```

Answer (score 3):

These are the types of constraints defined using this syntax `#[account(constraint = <expr>)]`.

From the anchor documentation:

```
Constraint that checks whether the given expression evaluates to true.
Use this when no other constraint fits your use case.

Example:


#[account(constraint = one.keys[0].age == two.apple.age)]
pub one: Account<'info, MyData>,
pub two: Account<'info, OtherData>
```